# How do I retrieve selected data from nested documents of type objects in mongodb

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, hierarchical-data

I'm having a tough time in defining mongo queries, reaching out to this forum for support

Here is my document:

- It follows a **Tree** aka Hierearchy model
- I have nested documents in this format below

What I'm trying to achieve?

- To be able to query only their immediate children at any point i.e **without returning grand childrens**
  i.e when we query for 111 sub document details:
  I only want to see

```
    "111" : {
            "_id" : 111,
            "type" : "parent",
            "children" : {
                "1111" : {
                    "_id" : "1111",
                    "type" : "parent"
                },
                "1112" : {
                    "_id" : "1112",
                    "type" : "parent",
                }
            }
        }
```

**Here is the Main Document:**

```
{
    "_id" : 11,
    "type" : "parent",
    "children" : {
        "111" : {
            "_id" : 111,
            "type" : "parent",
            "children" : {
                "1111" : {
                    "_id" : "1111",
                    "type" : "parent",
                    "children" : {
                        "11111" : {
                            "type" : "parent",
                            "_id" : "11111",
                            "children" : {}
                        }
                    }
                },
                "1112" : {
                    "_id" : "1112",
                    "type" : "parent",
                    "children" : {
                        "11112" : {
                            "_id" : "11112",
                            "children" : {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "112" : {
            "_id" : "112",
            "type" : "parent",
            "children" : {}
        },
        "113" : {
            "_id" : "113",
            "type" : "parent",
            "children" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: If children were in the form of array instead of nested objects then your query would look something like db.your_db_name.find({}, {"children.children": 0}) but as its object we cannot directly put a * value to look out for all the keys existing inside it with a direct query.

Comment: True, it was array initially. But to serve the use cases of updation. I changed to be a nested object , now retrieval has become a bottleneck

Comment: Back to array! working with variable keys is just one of the worst idea. And ask for updates if needed, there're tools (update operators) to update the appropriated entry of an array.